# Is it possible to deserialize the same JSON property twice using Jackson library?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm working on a microservice using Spring Boot and I need to deserialize JSON. I'm using the Jackson library for this purpose. I was wondering if it's possible to deserialize the same JSON property twice: once with a custom deserializer and once as-is, without altering its value.

I tried something like this:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = generateOrgKey.class)
@JsonProperty("registry_link") 
private String organizationKey; 
@JsonProperty("registry_link") 
private String registryLink;
```

This doesn't work because it generates conflicts between the two getter methods that Jackson generates (I think). I'm curious if it's possible to achieve this using Jackson functionality or another approach. I also attempted to use `@JsonAlias`, but it was unsuccessful.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand: you are receiving a Json which has twice the same key "registry_link"? How is that possible?

Comment: What is the body of your custom deserializer class?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ No, the JSON has only one key "registry_link", but I want to handle its value differently hence the custom deserializer, yet I also intend to preserve its original value, hence the second String field.. Perhaps I'm trying to do something thas isn't formally correct.

Comment: @MeysamKarimi check it out here: https://codeshare.io/J7bDly

Comment: It might be easier to provide a `setRegistryLink` method (called during standard JSON deserialization) that does the manipulation and sets `organizationKey` when it's null.

Comment: @AndrewS How can I call it during standard deserialization? I'm not sure about it.

Comment: [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations#4-jsonsetter) is an @JsonSetter example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to set one field using the setter of the other - the default serialization/deserialization uses getters and setters:

```
public class Pojo {

  @JsonIgnore
  private String organizationKey;
  @JsonProperty(value = "registry_link")
  private String registryLink;

  //no args constructor

  //getters

  public void setRegistryLink(String registryLink) {
    this.registryLink = registryLink;
    this.organizationKey = registryLink;
  }
}
```

`organizationKey` is ignored so it does not get serialized.

Another option is to use custom deserializer on the class level, but I can't think of a way which does not set all properties manually (undesirable) or does not depend on another instance of `ObjectMapper` (also undesirable).